# django.apps apps.get_model('app_name.model_name') finds no models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and using Django 2.1.7.

Up to today, I have had a (simple) working system. Then I needed to introduce a circular dependency between two of my model classes, which creates circular imports and causes problems, etc...

I have read that since Django 1.7 the proper way to import a circular dependency between models is:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import models

Model2 = apps.get_model('my_app.Model2')

class Model1(models.Model):
    # use Model2 where needed
```

However, I always see the error:

> LookupError: App 'my_app' doesn't have a 'Model2' model.

Note that both `Model1` and `Model2` are in the same app, so I have tried calling `apps.get_model()` both with and without the app prefix.

If I just remove the circular dependency (ie: `Model1` no longer references `Model2`), both models work just fine in the system independently. DB queries work, `makemigrations` works, `migrate` works, etc...

And to be sure, in my `settings.py` file: I have 'my_app' declared at the top of the `INSTALLED_APPS` array. I also tried moving it to the bottom.

What gives? Seems so simple I don't know what I could be missing.

Do I need to register my models somewhere else explicitly?

Comment: If Model1 and Model2 are in the same app. Then they should be in the same file too

Comment: Thanks! But, really...how does that scale for bigger apps? Admittedly very new to Django.

Anyway, I tried your suggestions just to see, and I still see the same error.

Additionally you have the problem with the same file: class A is declared first and uses class B which is declared second which happens to use class A. class B doesn't complain, but class A does, because it doesn't yet know about Class B. Switch the order of their declarations and the the problem reverses.

Newb Django questions! :-)

Comment: If your problem is defining model fields for relations you can also use the string syntax: `my_field = models.ForeignKey('Model2')` or `my_field = models.ForeignKey('my_app.Model2')`...

Comment: yeah I tried using the string form before I read about using `get_model()`. Both end up with the same error.

Comment: `get_model()` can fail because apps may not be loaded yet, string syntax *should* work without problems.

Comment: Sorry guys, this was a bit of a wild goose chase. The error I was getting was not the real problem at all. There was an error in one of my many-to-many mappings, but the error kept saying it there was a lookup error. After continuing to simplify my setup down, I figured out it was a mapping problem, not a lookup error problem. Misleading error messages!